# Can't call function (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have button

```
    <input type="button" value="Показать URL" onclick="showUrlQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')">
```

this is my onclick function

```
function showUrlQuestionnaire(id) {
$('#show_url_dialog').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Questionnaire/ShowUrlQuestionnaire', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', data: { id: id }, contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                success: function (ajaxResult) {
                    $('#url-container').html(ajaxResult);
                }
            });
        }
```

this is my modal window

```
@section dialogs{

<div id="show_url_dialog" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4>Link:</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="url-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

and this is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ShowUrlQuestionnaire(int id)
    {
        var questionnaire = QuestionnaireRepository.GetById(id);
        var questionnaireUrl = "/Questionnaire/CompleteQuestionnaire?GuidToken=" + questionnaire.QuestionnaireId.ToString();
        return Json(questionnaireUrl, "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

but when I click on button nothing happens like my ajax-request doesn't work.
What's wrong and how to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried using your browser debugger to figure out if your javascript fires? and what it returns?

Comment: What is `' + options.rowId + '`

Comment: `options.rowId` is int number of row getting from MVC jQGrid, so on page code of my button looks like `<input type="button" value="Show URL" onclick="showUrlQuestionnaire(2)">`

Comment: Try calling your controller directly through the browser via a url, then hardcode that url in your jquery ajax function.  See if these are successful then adjust.  This will help you determine if the issue is on the client or server side.

Comment: Any js errors in your browser debugger console?

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox If I try calling my controller directly through the browser via a url like `http://localhost:17000/Questionnaire/ShowUrlQuestionnaire/2` , I get the right data like `/Questionnaire/CompleteQuestionnaire?GuidToken=5e88f5ed-bf15-4b52-a64c-653965fbaa8f`

Comment: Ok, now hard code that url in your jquery ajax call.  If it works, it tells you something is wrong with the url your supplying

Comment: In my ajax call I have `url: 'Questionnaire/ShowUrlQuestionnaire'` but I also need to pass url with id every time, I tried to change code `url: 'Questionnaire/ShowUrlQuestionnaire' + id, type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', data: { id: id }, contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'` but when I click on button nothing happens again.

Comment: I tried to use debugger, it works right on `$('#show_url_dialog').modal('show');` and then it looks like jumps over other all code in `showUrlQuestionnaire` function(

Comment: Have you tried data: JSON.stringify({id: id}) as you are specifying your contentType as 'application/json;charset=utf-8',

Comment: Thanks a lot for help all of you, I have found my mistake, I was need to use url `$.ajax({
                url: 'ShowUrlQuestionnaire',` controller name was unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

why you are using onclick ? just use jquery click event

```
 <input type="button" value="Показать URL" class="btn" data-id="2">
```

where data-id is your = options.rowId 
and then

```
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
 var id =$(this).data("id");
 $('#show_url_dialog').modal('show');
 $.ajax({
        url: 'Questionnaire/ShowUrlQuestionnaire', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', data: { id: id },  contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    success: function (ajaxResult) {
      $('#url-container').html(ajaxResult);
      }
 });
}
```

From my point of view inline javascript is evil thing

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, I have found my mistake, I was need to use url `$.ajax({
                url: 'ShowUrlQuestionnaire',` controller name was unnecessary here.

Comment: And yes, I agree with your opinion about inline javascript function but it is the project's standart, unfortunately.